# How copy,Paste is working form my local system to remote system

Tags: windows, copy-paste, dedicated-server

Recently we bought dedicated server with `Windows`.I really surprised windows allowing me to copy files(CTRL+C) from my local system and paste files(CTRL+P) in dedicated server.Vice versa.

Before we tried Linux dedicated server.If you want transfer file from local system(Windows) to dedicated server(Linux),I need to use `FTP`.But in windows server all these are not needed.

I have a curiosity to know,How the procedure is working internally.For this I search allot,But I didn't found clear materials.So If you know any good material,suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your question is precisely. Are you using remote desktop to log into your windows server, and then copying and pasting files between your local system and the remote server? If that's the case, then the copying and pasting is happening within your "remote desktop" client. It's not really related to your server's operating system, per se.

Comment: I can copy files from my local system and paste in remote system.I want to know how it is working.For this Microsoft using is there any File Transfer protocol.

Comment: How are you logging into the remote system? Using the windows "Remote Desktop" client?

Comment: I am connecting remote system using `Remote Desktop connection` option from my local system.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. That RDC application is doing some extra magic in the background for you. It's using FTP or something similar to emulate copy and paste behavior for you between machines. You don't NEED to use FTP to transfer files between your local machine and your linux server. You could use SCP from a cygwin terminal, the git bash terminal, or other. There may even be a remote desktop application you could use to log into your linux server, which could conceivably have similar copy/paste emulation. That is.. if you have a desktop environment installed on your server.